# Как получить текст вместо ссылки android.content.res.Resourses$Theme@e87d8e

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я записываю данные из EditText в словарь, обрабатываю с помощью JSON и сохраняю в файл.

```
public class AddWord
{
    Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public AddWord(String word, String translation, String themeStr, Context context)
    {
        dictionary.setArrayList(new Theme(themeStr, new WordAndTranslation(word, translation)));
        JSONHelper.exportToJSON(context, dictionary);
    }
}
```

Затем по нажатию кнопки TextView присваивается значение (название темы). Функция Test() срабатывает по кнопке BUTTON на скрине.

```
var dictionary: Dictionary = Dictionary()

fun Test(view: View)
{
    dictionary = JSONHelper.importFromJSON(this)
    var text = dictionary.getArrayList().get(0).getTheme()
    textView.text = text
}
```

Помогите разобраться почему вместо данных введенных через EditText, я получаю ссылку (word, translation - это названия EditText; theme - AutoCompleteTextView).

```
fun AddWord(view: View)
{
    val addWord: AddWord = AddWord(word.text.toString(), 
        translation.text.toString(), theme.toString(), this)
    var mainIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(mainIntent)
}
```

Но если я просто присвою значения для word, tranlation, theme, то все работает

```
fun Training(view: View)
{
    theme.setTheme("test")
    theme.setArrayList(WordAndTranslation("test1", "test2"))
    dictionary.setArrayList(theme)
    JSONHelper.exportToJSON(this, dictionary)

    var trainingIntent = Intent(this, TrainingActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(trainingIntent)
}
```

Вот еще сами классы

```
public class Dictionary
{
    private ArrayList<Theme> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setArrayList(Theme theme)
    {
        arrayList = getArrayList();
        this.arrayList.add(theme);
    }

    public ArrayList<Theme> getArrayList()
    {
        return arrayList;
    }
}

public class Theme
{
    private String Theme;
    private ArrayList<WordAndTranslation> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Theme() {}

    public Theme(String theme, WordAndTranslation wordAndTranslation)
    {
        setTheme(theme);
        setArrayList(wordAndTranslation);
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme)
    {
        Theme = theme;
    }

    public String getTheme()
    {
        return Theme;
    }

    public void setArrayList(WordAndTranslation wordAndTranslation)
    {
        this.arrayList.add(wordAndTranslation);
    }

    public ArrayList<WordAndTranslation> getArrayList()
    {
        return arrayList;
    }
}

public class WordAndTranslation
{
    private String Word;
    private String Translation;

    public WordAndTranslation(String word, String translation)
    {
        Word = word;
        Translation = translation;
    }

    public void setWord(String word)
    {
        Word = word;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return Word;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation)
    {
        Translation = translation;
    }

    public String getTranslation()
    {
        return Translation;
    }
}
```

[image: MainActivity[![AddWordActivity[![TrainingActivity]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCjW7.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn3Dp.jpg)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может быть проблема в том, что у вас `theme.toString()`, а не `theme.text.toString()`?

Comment: Похоже что у вас происходит путаница со свойством `theme` - попробуйте не использовать это имя для своих переменных, тогда ситуация должна разъясниться

Comment: Спасибо, проблема оказалась в том, что переменная theme использовалась в res.Resourses (т.е. создавалась автоматически). Я поменял название EditText и все заработало.